# Ping TTL exceeded

Tags: ping

When I try to ping some far away destinations (e.g. mx20.india.com), I always get a TTL exceeded response (even with the maximum value of 255).

My question: is there any other way to reach these servers?

Comment: It is entirely possible that this is a stale MX entry and they decommissioned the subnet the server was on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their network is broken.  Specifically their two routers, 180.179.87.44 ( which their DNS also erroneously identifies as mx20.india.com ) and 180.179.87.43 have a circular route and keep bouncing the packets back and forth until they time out.  You can see this by running `trouceroute`.

They will need to fix their broken routers for you to reach this server.

Comment: When I ran traceroute, the packages got routed first to some routers of Tata communication, but around TTL 24, I no longer see any information at all.

How exactly could you see the problem lies with the owners of india.com?

Comment: @JeffersonB, because for me, after hop 23, it started bouncing back and forth between those two routers.